# Conversion of continous value to discrete in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression

How can I take continious data as a dependent varibale in logistic regression using python?

Comment: You mean a continuous function? A time series?

Comment: Suppose I have some values example:0.45,.67,.89,.345. If value less than. 5 it will generate 0, if greater than . 5 it will return 1.

Comment: That looks like an if statement to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.cut` like given below:

```
pd.cut(df, bins=2, labels=np.arange(2), right=False)
```